# iOS and Android devices ID tracking

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I can't get any solution for this. Maybe You have an idea for this:

I have an app on App Store and Google Play. The app costs about $10. What I want to do now is to update this app, make it free but also add the login screen. The users will have to buy subscription on third party website.
The problem:
There are already some users who purchased the paid app version and when I will update the app they will loose what they payd for.
I was thinking about submitting an update for the paid app, that would somehow track the devices IDs, then after getting the IDs list, update the app for the free version with login, but all the devices with tracked IDs would have the subscription for one year more. 
I just dont hnow how to track those IDs and if this is possible. 
Maybe You have a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use IMEI of the phone to do that.

android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

Answer (score 0):

The only identifier you can use on iOS is the vendor identifier. This may change if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled